# Spark word count in Scala (running in Apache Sandbox)

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to do a word count lab in Spark on Scala. I am able to successfully load the text file into a variable (RDD), but when I do the .flatmap, .map, and reduceByKey, I receive the attached error message. I am new to this, so any type of help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know.[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxAVh.jpg)

Comment: You are not able to successfully load your file. In the line `sc.textFile(...)` (try something like this `sc.textFile(myNonExistingFile.txt)`) you just initialize your data, but not transformation. When you call `flatMap` the execution starts and you get error, because the file does not exists. Referring https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

Your program is failing because it was not able to detect the file present on Hadoop

Need to specify the file in the following format

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://namenodedetails:8020/input.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the complete qualified path of the file. Since Spark builds a Dependency graph and evaluates lazily when an action is called, you are facing the error when you are trying to call an action.

It is better to debug after reading the file from HDFS using .first or .take(n) methods